# Grafana dashboard causing Firefox browser crash

Tags: mysql, firefox, grafana

I am using Status map Panel in Grafana in order to visualize states of some machines in real time. the wanted time-range is last 8 Hours and the data must be showed every 1 second.
I am using MySQL as database und my query looks like this:

```
 SELECT
  $__timeGroupAlias(creation_date,1s,previous),
  Workplace AS metric,
  MachineState
FROM fahrtenschreiber
WHERE
  $__timeFilter(creation_date) AND Area = 'Bereich_Vorhobel'
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY Sortnumber ASC
```

This query is causing the crash of Firefox browser.
Can anyone help?? Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you trying to run the query every 1 second?

Comment: I am trying to run it every 30 second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> time-range is last 8 Hours and the data must be showed every 1 second

I guess you mean data with 1 sec time aggregation.

Math: 8 hours x 60 minutes x 60 seconds x 1 datapoint/sec = 28800 data points

Top display has 4k resolution usually, so it is impossible to visualize 28.8k time series datapoints with 4k pixels properly + you have problem with memory exhaustion, so Firefox is crashing.

Use time aggregation (10 sec seem to be reasonable in this case) or shorter time range => less datapoints will be returned and browser won't need so much memory.

Of course you can try other way and you can add more memory to your system, but it will be just workaround and not proper solution.